# Redis keys deleted before expiration

Tags: redis

I use redis on Ubuntu machine to store some keys with expiration, but in testing server (Ubuntu) my keys get deleted/disappears before expiration. Key was set to expire for 24hours but was already gone after 4 hours or so.

I know that ttl is correct and set in seconds and I do not see any key flush in history.

I also checked redis info `maxmemory:0` (not set) and `evicted_keys:0`, so I assume it is not memory problem.

What could cause removal of my keys?

Maybe there is some script in server that might delete keys? If so how could I track such script?

Comment: Is there a chance that your Redis server is open to the world without a password? That's usually the reason...

Comment: What @ItamarHaber is referring to could be verified by running 'info commandstats' command. It prints the number of del calls in the field 'cmdstat_del' calls. Another thing you can check is the clients connected to Redis by running 'client list' and see if there are any odd IP addresses connected.

Comment: @rainhacker sorry for late reply, as I understand you can connect to redis only when  you are inside the ubuntu server (server and redis ip`s are different and I cant connnect from my local machine). `cmdstat_flushall:calls=45` I guess someone flushes my keys, is there anyway to track this other than `monitor` since this happens on rare occasions and there are a lot of ping call in redis so it is hard to track it.

Comment: Tracking the offender is hard. I suggest that you just use the `rename-command` directive to disable flushall and then look for the person complaining about errors ;)

Comment: @zerociudo You should be able to [connect to Redis](https://redis.io/topics/rediscli) from any machine as long as the [bind config](http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf) is correctly set. Also, can't you pipe the monitor command output to a file and grep it later like this `redis-cli -h xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx -p xxxx monitor  > monitor.txt &` WARNING: dont' do this in production as it will bring down the performance of Redis